# Using a when statement and a custom code inside it

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this code where i want to implement a complex piece in when statement so i can fix the issue, there are several when statements after the one which i am showing

```
when d.ID in (1,2,3) and d.today <= '10/11/2018' AND (
select count(1)
    from table1 sc
    inner join table2 c on c.ID = sc.ID
    inner join table3 tc on tc.ID = sc.ID
    where sc.sid = 4
    and sc.fid is not null
    and c.fid = d.facultyid
    group by sc.sNum,sc.Fid,sc.todaydate,c.ID,tc.cnum
) B > 5 then 500 else 520 end
```

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'B'.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Remove the alias for your subquery. You don't alias subquery when used in boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spurious table alias `B`.  Remove it

```
(select count(1)
    from table1 sc
    inner join table2 c on c.ID = sc.ID
    inner join table3 tc on tc.ID = sc.ID
    where sc.sid = 4
    and sc.fid is not null
    and c.fid = d.facultyid
    group by sc.sNum,sc.Fid,sc.todaydate,c.ID,tc.cnum
) > 5
```

I should note that you are likely to now get an error that the subquery returns more than one row.  If so, ask *another* question.  This question has been answered.

Include sample data, desired results, an explanation of what the query should do, and a (perhaps simplified) version of your existing query.

Comment: a side can i use a count inside the when condition like this: `when d.ID in (1,2,3) then case when d.todayDate >= '02/21/2018' AND d.count(1) > 5 then 111 else 222 end`

Comment: @John . . . `d.count(1)` doesn't mean anything in SQL, unless you have a schema named `d` and have defined a UDF called `count()`.

Comment: basically the d is the join to the table after that above statement

Comment: @John . . . That syntax does not work for what you intend to do.

Comment: so what can be the fix for that, can you provide me help regards to the above line i indicated

Comment: @John . . . You should ask a question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  A query snippet taken out of context is often not sufficient.